# [HTML]how to upload values in the <fieldset> element if the <fieldset> tag is outside of the <form> tag

Tags: html, fieldset

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Javascript</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/check" id="demo" method="post" name="demo">
            <input type="text" name="username" />username
            <button type="button"
                onclick="form.change_color.style.backgroundColor='#00FF00';">change
                fieldset background</button>
            <button type="button"
                onclick="activateFieldset()">activate fieldset</button>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
        <fieldset form="demo" name="change_color">
            <input type="password" name="password" />password
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset form="demo" disabled="disabled" name="license" id="license">
            <input type="text" name="license_id" />license_id
        </fieldset>
        <script>
            function activateFieldset(){
                var e = document.getElementById("license");
                e.disabled = "";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I fill in `a`, `b` and `c` into the `username`, `change_color` and `license_id` text box, but the browser only upload the data in `username`.

I tried Chrome/Opera/Firefox, they all worked like that.

Can anyone tell me why the browser doesn't upload the data in the  element?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Because what you are trying is incorrect. If you want elements to be passed in the form post then they NEED to be in the form tags. They cannot be outside. The alternative is to build the data using JS and then post it.

Comment: _“Can anyone tell me why the browser doesn't upload the data in the element?”_ – for the same reason that the post office is not able to deliver the sheet of paper that you had laying _next to the letter_ you send … The form is what gets submitted, and only elements inside the form are send. That’s how forms _work_; everything else would just not make sense.

Comment: Got it, thank you@haxtbh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike some commenters state, it is very possible to have [reassociateable elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#category-form-attr) *out of* a form, trough the use of an explicit `FORM` attribute, according to HTML5 RFC (though I agree that it is nicer to have them all grouped *within* the form).

And in your case, though you have specified well the `form` attribute in the fieldset, it happens that the elements which must have the `form` attribute are the INPUT ones.

Comment: yes, Santi, U R right, I change my code like what you said, and it works well:)

Comment: Fine. Splendid. :-)